# Acceessing some aggregate functions in a linq datasource in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I am working on a traditional WebForms project. In the project I am trying out some Linq datasources with plans to eventually migrate to an MVC architecture. I am still very new to Linq.

I have a GridView using a Linq datasource. The entities I am showing has a to many relationship and I would like to get the maximum value of a column in the many side of the relationship.

I can show properties of the base entity in the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="tJobBase.tJob.JobNumber">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tJobBase.tJob.JobNumber") %>'>
     </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I can also show the count of the many related property:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="tJobBase.tJob.tHourlies.Count">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tJobBase.tJob.tHourlies.Count") %>'>
     </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Is there a way to get the max value of a column called WeekEnding in the tHourlies collection to show in the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Bind("tJobBase.tJob.tHourlies.Max(w => WeekEnding)")
```

but I think it would be better to make an specific query wich returns in a field the max value you want, and bind this query to your gridview. Then you could access this field as usual with something like

```
Bind("MaxWeekEnding")
```

Comment: I tried using this before and I get the error that "A call to Bind was not well formatted." I experimented with calls such as this in code and it works fine. Is this just not available in Bind calls?

Comment: Did you try Eval instead of Bind?